# Is it possible to enroll in Starfleet Academy as an adult?

Tags: star-trek

What would happen to a person who wants to join Starfleet but is too old to be a regular student at Starfleet Academy? Could they still enroll at the Academy and take classes? If you were in your late 40s or something..

Comment: SF Academy is a highly competitive school. Only the best of the best get in.

Comment: I know, but say that there is an older person whose race has just joined the Federation, and he or she wants to enroll in the Academy. If they had the education and the experience, would they be able to get in despite their age?

Comment: Age is subjective. Vulcans live twice as long as humans (200+ years), but still mature at the same rate. Spock for example still enrolled in Starfleet Academy at 19 years old. A species that lives longer and matures at a relative pace (say adulthood at 40 instead of 18), no reason they would be barred from enrollment if they pass the test, imho. TOS apparently had a maximum retirement age of 75 for humans. In real life, the US armed forces has a maximum enrollment age of 42, while each branch actually has lower ones (28 marines, 38 army).

Comment: Given the parallels between Starfleet and US armed forces, most likely, there is some age of maximum enrollment, based on physical and mental requirements of the job, which would change based on the longer life-span of humans in TOS and TNG era (McCoy was still kicking as Admiral at 137). But one nice case is Tuvok, who was 25 when he enrolled, while most enroll at 18.

Comment: Alright thanks for clearing that up, I'm writing a story about a middle-aged Cardassian who joins Starfleet after the Dominion War so this little bit of info will help

Comment: Again, if there is a parallel with current armed forces, the academy is not the only way in. OCS (officer candidate school) provides more officers to US forces than the service academies. Additionally, enlisted and warrant personnel can buck for a commission.

Comment: @dmckee considering nu-Trek, everybody on the Enterprise and other ships seem to have been at the Academy, from rank & file to officers. And all we have heard about in the series have been the San Francisco Academy (aside from Enterprise maybe.), even O'Brian, who is not an officer, just enlisted. The idea of maximum enrollment age is simply about Ability to perform the tasks required.

Comment: @Lukas keep in mind, non-federation citizens need a commanding officer's recommendation to enter the academy (after passing the test). But there is always other methods of entry. Officer Exchange programs for one, as a Cardassian officer attached to Star Fleet, or a 3rd party contractor hired for his expertise in a given field, etc.

Comment: I may be getting things wrong but isn't nu!McCoy supposed to be in late 30s / 40s when he joined in?

Comment: @cde - nope. To be truly competitive, they should only take the best of the best of the best. Sir.

Comment: @Shisa Born 2227 like the real McCoy, enlisted 2255 alongside nu-Kirk. 28 years old.

Comment: @Lukas - BTW, the Cardassians don't join the Federation after the end of the Dominion War#

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course they could enter the Academy:

1. Garak cons Worf into agreeing to sponsor him for entry into Starfleet Academy in an episode of *DS9*
2. There is a Benzite adult attending the Academy in an episode of *TNG*, and
3. From lesser canon, James T. Kirk's nephew, Peter Kirk, attends Starfleet Academy while in his thirties during the novel *Sarek*.

Answer (score 11):

There appears to be no minimum or maximum age at which one can enrol in Starfleet Academy. At the lower end, we see [Wesley Crusher](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Wesley_Crusher) and [Peter Preston](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Peter_Preston) entering the Academy at a very young age (15 and 13 respectively) whereas [Garak](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/In_Purgatory's_Shadow_(episode)) (who seems to be in his 40's) nearly fools Worf into helping him to apply.

Certain specialist professions, especially those found within the Science divisions, would seem to be particularly susceptible to older applicants since a [qualified doctor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Leonard_McCoy_(alternate_reality)) or [computer expert](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Spock_(alternate_reality)) would already be joining with useful skills, potentially as a second career.

As far as your fic is concerned, your Cardassian character would just need the recommendation of a senior officer *and* the agreement of the Director of Starfleet Academy since he's not a member of the Federation and could easily be an agent of a foreign power or someone with a very shady history.

### Entry Requirements:

- You must be above the age of majority to apply yourself
  **or**
- You can apply at any age with the recommendation of a flag officer (and the consent of your parent/guardian) if you are below the age of majority

and

- You must be a member of the UFP
  **or**
- You must have the recommendation of a flag officer if you are a non-Fed Citizen

and

- You must be able to pass the gruelling physical and mental entry examinations.

---

The alternate route into Starfleet academy (e.g. transferring after enlisting as a crewman and becoming a Petty Officer) wouldn't be appropriate in this case.

Comment: In a real world military, there's also the existence of [Direct Commission Officers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_commission_officer). It's a way for people with particular advanced skills - doctors, for example - to join the military without attending a traditional military service academy. Based on conversations scattered throughout the series, I suspect Deana Troi would have be one, but the writers may not have been aware of the concept.

Comment: @T.J.L. - You may not have noticed, but Starfleet is filled with older-looking doctors and scientists. This is mostly because they've had careers before setting off into space.

Comment: Yes; those are the people that Direct Commission Officer programs are designed for. As working professionals in technical fields, they have a breadth and depth of experience that the military desires but doesn't always have the time or interest to develop organically/internally. They're given commissions *and* spared having to deal with all the snot-nosed, wet-behind-the-ears, (wo)man-children in the service academies.

Answer (score -3):

In my humble opinion there is no canonical listing of the rules so we can only deduce with uncertainty from the various stories.

*The Making of Star Trek* says that Kirk entered Starfleet Academy aged 17, the minimum age, and I think that the writers guide also said that.

For over a century the United states service  academies have accepted cadets aged seventeen to twenty two  and had four year programs.  Thus most cadets graduate aged twenty one to twenty six.  It is normal to enter aged eighteen after graduating from high school.

Even though the normal course lasts four years, I have found examples of cadets who graduated West Point after more than four years.  Thus Merrick washing out of Starfleet Academy in his fifth year is not inconsistent with it being a four year institution.

In times of war and impending war, cadets were sometimes graduated ahead of time.  Thus a relative of mine officially enrolled in West Point on his seventeenth birthday and graduated three years and three weeks later aged barely more than twenty, and he was not the youngest graduate during the 20th century.

I suppose that for Earth-Human Federation citizens who decide in high school (or equivalent) that they want to enter Starsfleet the same entrance age requirements are used, age seventeen to twenty two.

I suppose that there is a separate entrance program for Earth-Human Federation citizens who decide later in life that they want to enter Starfleet but I know nothing about the age requirements for that hypothetical program.

And it seems likely that there is a separate program to enroll a few young geniuses each year at ages younger than the main program allows. Wesley Crusher may have been competing for one of those rare genius admissions in "Coming of Age", and failed, but no doubt later easily aced the test for the regular enrollment.

Ensign Chekov, the alternate Universe Chekov of *Star Trek* (2009), Spock, Doctor Elizabeth Dehner, and Peter Preston may have been enrolled in that program for young geniuses.

And age requirements for nonhuman beings to enter Starfleet Academy may have been more or less similar with various adjustments for their different rates of intellectual and physical growth.

Of course my impression that the main system of enrollment for Earth-Humans in Starfleet Academy has the same age limits as contemporary American service academies may be incorrect.